# Proverb for weak individuals uniting their power and manage to defeat stronger opponent

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests, proverb-requests

I'm looking for an idiom or proverb describing a situation where (otherwise weak and insignificant) individuals/actors decide to join their forces to defeat a much stronger opponent, and they successfully manage to do so. A Hungarian equivalent would be "plenty of geese defeats a pig".

Answer (score 2):

**There is strength in numbers** (idiom/saying)

> Used to say that a group of people has more influence or power than
> one person [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/there%20is%20strength%20in%20numbers)

> What Strength in numbers means is a phrase used to express that in a
> group, far more can be done compared to something alone.
> [urbandictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Strength%20in%20numbers)

---

> Like the ant, one of the ways to be wise in your weakness is by
> relying on others. Ants take advantage of their numbers because they
> understand that **there is strength in numbers**. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Be_An_Ant/UlP5DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22there%20is%20strength%20in%20numbers%22%20weak&pg=PT71&printsec=frontcover).

> You are probably familiar with the saying: **Strength in Numbers**. Well
> there is strength in family as well. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Wealth_Building_Strategies_of_the_Super/olGfgs1wyfwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=saying%20%22strength%20in%20numbers%22&pg=PT51&printsec=frontcover).

> Third, it saw **strength in numbers**, assuming that with unity the Arabs
> would become a force hard to defeat.  [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Modern_Middle_East_Third_Edition/z7MwDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22strength%20in%20numbers%22%20defeat&pg=PA90&printsec=frontcover).

> What I am saying is **there is strength in numbers** if rural areas work
> together, in terms of access to capital, in terms of starting to
> develop some kind of pwerbase. Small individual rural institutions
> really do not have any powerbase from which to work from. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Examination_of_Rural_Hospitals_Under_the/8FZZk1If8HwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=saying%20%22strength%20in%20numbers%22&pg=PA195&printsec=frontcover).

> This Luganda saying means that teeth can only bite meat when they are
> clenched together. This is akin to some English sayings for example
> **there is strength in numbers**... [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Understanding_Ubuntu_for_Enhancing_Inter/kMgpEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=saying%20%22strength%20in%20numbers%22&pg=PA234&printsec=frontcover).

---

Examples in book titles:

*[The **Strength in Numbers**: The New Science of Team Science](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Strength_in_Numbers/LffWDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22strength%20in%20numbers%22&printsec=frontcover)*

*[**Strength in Numbers**: Population, Reproduction, and Power in Eighteenth-Century France](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Strength_in_Numbers/TgkaWS7yDl8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22strength%20in%20numbers%22&printsec=frontcover)*

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proverb: "*United we stand, divided we fall.*". ([ref.](https://quotes.yourdictionary.com/articles/who-said-united-we-stand-divided-we-fall.html))

> The popular motto "United we stand, divided we fall," often shortened to "united we stand," is commonly used to express unity and collaboration. The phrase is used to encourage and inspire. It sends the message that working together is easier, as there is strength in numbers, whereas doing things alone is harder and invites failure. This phrase has been used time and again throughout history to rally groups together. You will still hear it used today where the message remains the same. In some ways, it can be considered a catchphrase.

Answer (score 0):

***[Unity is strength](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/unity_is_strength)***

also:

> unity makes strength,
> union makes strength,
> union is strength.

meaning:

> Being united makes us become stronger.

(Wiktionary)

Answer (score 0):

"Death of a thousand cuts"

> A slow death by the torture of many small wounds, none lethal in itself, but fatal in their cumulative effect. This torture was a form of execution in ancient China, reserved for the most heinous crime.
> [Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/6/messages/433.html#:%7E:text=DEATH%20OF%20A%20THOUSAND%20CUTS%20%2D%20%22A%20slow%20death%20by%20the,for%20the%20most%20heinous%20crime.)